# How to print a Sort of Array Vector I sort already in function but can't printf need some suggestion

Tags: c

Can't print after to sort array of vector I think my algorithm is correctly. the things I want is to print *CalVector after sort already but  its error after I compile invalid types float[int] for array subscript any suggest pls ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float Vector[7],*CalVector[7];
void Menu (){
    printf("################## MENU ##################\n");
    printf("1. Find the maximum number in the vector\n");
    printf("2. Find the minimum number in the vector\n");
    printf("3. Find the total of numbers in the vector\n");
    printf("4. Sort numbers in the vector in the ascending order\n");
    printf("0. Quit Program\n");
}
```

this is my sortVector function

```
   float sortVector()  {
    int i;
    float Sort,SwapVector;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
      if(*CalVector[i-1]>*CalVector[i]){
      SwapVector = *CalVector[i];
      *CalVector[i] = *CalVector[i-1];
      *CalVector[i] = SwapVector;
  }
}
}
float findMin() {
int i;
float Min ;
for (i =0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
    Min += *CalVector[i];
}
for (i = 0 ; i < 7 ;i++){
    if(*CalVector[i] < Min)
    Min = *CalVector[i];
}
return Min;
}
float findMax() {
int i;
float Max = 0 ;
for(i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
    if(*CalVector[i] > Max){
    Max = *CalVector[i];
}
}
return Max;
}
float findSum() {
int i;
float Sum = 0;
for( i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
    Sum += *CalVector[i];
}
return Sum;
}
int main () {
int Count,Choice;
float MaxiumVector,Min,Sum,Sort ;
printf("Enter 7 numbers into the vector: ");
    for(Count=0;Count<7;Count++){
        scanf("%f",&Vector[Count]);
    }
    for (Count = 0; Count<7;Count++){
        CalVector[Count]=&Vector[Count];
    //      printf("%f",*CalVector[Count]);
    }
    do{
    Menu();
    printf("Enter your choice <1, 2, 3, 4 or 0> : ");
    scanf("%d",&Choice);
    switch (Choice) {
    case 1  :  printf("%.2f",findMax()); break;
    case 2  :  printf("%.2f",findMin()); break;
    case 3  :  printf("%.2f",findSum()); break;
```

and case 4 that i want to print

```
    case 4  :  for(Count = 0; Count < 7; Count++){
        Sort = sortVector();
        printf("%.2f",Sort[Count]);
    }
    default :  printf("Invalid Choice!!\n");
}
}while(Choice!=0);
 printf("");
  return 0 ;
}
```

any suggestion for another code for more comfortable i'm just beginner of coding :D

Comment: Why is `Max` an `int`?

Comment: Also: To find the _maximum_, do not initialize as with `Max = 0;` as all values in the vector could be negative.  Suggest `Max = *CalVector[0];`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable called `Max` in `findMax` hides the global `Max`, so setting `Max` in the function doesn't affect the global.  You do return this value from the function, however you don't do anything with that return value:

```
case 1  : findMax(); 
        printf("%f",Max);
```

You need to assign the return value to `Max`:

```
case 1  : Max = findMax(); 
        printf("%f",Max);
```

Also, you should define `Max` in `findMax` as a `float`, otherwise you'll get truncated values.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would advice you not to use globals, but if you want to do that, you could just remove the declaration of `Max` in `findMax`. That declaration hides the global variable.

Another thing (that your compiler should have warned you about) is that inside `findMax` you declared `Max` as an int, but it should be a float. That problem disappears if you remove the declaration, but I think I should point it out.

One more thing is that if you're using globals (which I, again, advice you not to do) there's no real need to return any value at all. You can write `findMax` like this:

```
void findMax() {
  int i;
  Max = *CalVector[0];
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (*CalVector[i] > Max) {
      printf("Max %f  Calvector %f", Max, *CalVector[i]);
      Max = *CalVector[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Comment 1 and 2 I get like this i try to declaration global value from Max and now i create Max in Main function and its can't compile because they don't know main how I can fix this ?

*P.M. I fix this by make `findMax()` as float and return value `Max`to main
and used assign like answer 2 `Max = findMax()` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
float Vector[7],*CalVector[7];
void Menu (){
    printf("################## MENU ##################\n");
    printf("1. Find the maximum number in the vector\n");
    printf("2. Find the minimum number in the vector\n");
    printf("3. Find the total of numbers in the vector\n");
    printf("4. Sort numbers in thevector in the ascending order\n");
    printf("0. Quit Program\n");
}
float findMax() {
  int i;
  float Max = 0 ;
    Max = *CalVector[0];
    for(i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
    if(*CalVector[i] > Max){
    Max = *CalVector[i];
}
}   
}
int main () {
int Count,Choice;
float Max = 0 ;
printf("Enter 7 numbers into the vector: ");
    for(Count=0;Count<7;Count++){
        scanf("%f",&Vector[Count]);
    }
    for (Count = 0; Count<7;Count++){
        CalVector[Count]=&Vector[Count];
    //      printf("%f",*CalVector[Count]);
    }
    Menu();
    printf("Enter your choice <1, 2, 3, 4 or 0> : ");
    scanf("%d",&Choice);
    switch (Choice) {
    case 1  : Max = findMax(); 
            printf("%f",Max);
    default : ;
}
return 0 ;
}
```